# Android - No such table: Materia in existing table

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, inner-join

I have two tables `Materias`(discipline) and `Grade`(grid).
First I call the activity from the table `Materias` and insert some rows, then I call the `Grade` activity. It has one reference column from `Materias`, but when I inner join these tables, I get Fatal Exception saying this message:

```
SQLiteException: no such table: Materias (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT g.*, c.Descricao FROM Grades g INNER JOIN Materias m ON  m.id = g.materia"
```

My MateriaDAO

```
public class MateriaDAO extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public final String tabela = "Materias";

    public MateriaDAO(Context context) {
        super(context, "Materias", null, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String comando = "CREATE TABLE " + tabela + " (";
        comando += "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,";
        comando += "Descricao TEXT,";
        comando += "Comentario TEXT,";
        comando += "Qtd_Aulas INTEGER,";
        comando += "Qtd_Faltas INTEGER)";
        db.execSQL(comando);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tabela;
        db.execSQL(sql);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insert(Materia o) {    
        try{
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("Descricao", o.getDescricao());
            cv.put("Comentario", o.getComentario());
            cv.put("Qtd_Aulas", o.getQtdAula());
            cv.put("Qtd_Faltas", o.getQtdAula());
            getWritableDatabase().insert(tabela, null, cv);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public void update(Materia o) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("Descricao", o.getDescricao());
        cv.put("Comentario", o.getComentario());
        cv.put("Qtd_Aulas", o.getQtdAula());
        cv.put("Qtd_Faltas", o.getQtdAula());
        String[] args = {o.getID() + ""};
        getWritableDatabase().update(tabela, cv, "ID=?", args);
    }

    public void delete(Materia o) {
        String[] args = {o.getID() + ""};
        getWritableDatabase().delete(tabela, "ID = ?", args);
    }

    public Materia preencher(Materia o) {
        String comando = "SELECT * FROM " + tabela + " WHERE ID " + o.getID();
        Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(comando, null);

        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            Materia m = new Materia();
            m.setDescricao(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Descricao")));
            m.setComentario(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Comentario")));
            m.setQtdAula(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Qtd_Aulas"))));
            m.setQtd_faltas(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Qtd_Faltas"))));

            return m;
        } else {
            return  null;
        }
    }

    public List<Materia> listar() {
        String comando = "SELECT * FROM " + tabela;
        Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(comando, null);

        List<Materia> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Materia m;

        while(c.moveToNext()) {
            m = new Materia();
            m.setDescricao(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Descricao")));
            m.setComentario(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Comentario")));
            m.setQtdAula(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Qtd_Aulas"))));
            m.setQtd_faltas(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Qtd_Faltas"))));

            list.add(m);
        }

        return list;
    }

    public boolean checarTabelaVazia() {
        String comando = "SELECT * FROM " + tabela;
        Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(comando, null);
        return c.moveToFirst();
    }

    public void addFalta(Materia o) {
        String comando = "SELECT * FROM " + tabela + " WHERE ID " + o.getID();
        Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(comando, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            int faltas = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Qtd_Faltas"));
            faltas++;

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("Qtd_Faltas", faltas);
            String[] args = {o.getID() + ""};
            getWritableDatabase().update(tabela, cv, "ID=?", args);
        }
    }
}
```

My GradeDAO

```
public class GradeDAO extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private final String tabela = "Grades";

    Context context;

    public GradeDAO(Context context) {
        super(context, "Grades", null, 2); this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String comando = "CREATE TABLE " + tabela + " (";
        comando += "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,";
        comando += "Materia INTEGER,";
        comando += "Periodo TEXT,";
        comando += "Dia_Semana INTEGER)";

        db.execSQL(comando);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tabela;
        db.execSQL(sql);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insert(Grade o){

        try{
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("Materia", o.getMateria());
            cv.put("Periodo", o.getPeriodo());
            cv.put("Dia_Semana", o.getDiaSemana());
            getWritableDatabase().insert(tabela, null, cv);
        }catch (Exception ex){

            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public void update(Grade o){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("Materia", o.getMateria());
        cv.put("Periodo", o.getPeriodo());
        cv.put("Dia_Semana", o.getDiaSemana());
        String[] args = {o.getID() + ""};
        getWritableDatabase().update(tabela, cv, "ID=?", args);
    }

    public void delete(Grade o){
        String[] args = {o.getID() + ""};
        getWritableDatabase().delete(tabela, "ID = ?", args);
    }

    public boolean checarTabelaVazia(){
        String comando = "SELECT * FROM " + tabela;
        Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(comando, null);
        return c.moveToFirst();
    }

    public Grade preencher(Grade gg){
        String comando = "SELECT g.*, c.Descricao FROM " + tabela + " g ";
        comando += " INNER JOIN Materia m ON  m.id = g.materia ";
        comando += " WHERE g.id = " + gg.getID();
        Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(comando, null);

        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            Grade o = new Grade();
            o.setID_Materia(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Materia")));
            o.setMateria(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Descricao")));
            o.setPeriodo(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Periodo")));
            o.setDiaSemana(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Dia_Semana")));

            return o;
        }
        else{
            return  null;
        }
    }

    public List<Grade> listar(){
        MateriaDAO dao = new MateriaDAO(context);
        List<Materia> m = dao.listar();

        String comando = "SELECT g.*, c.Descricao FROM " + tabela + " g ";
        comando += " JOIN " + dao.tabela + " m ON  m.id = g.materia ";
        Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(comando, null);

        List<Grade> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Grade o;

        while(c.moveToNext()){
            o = new Grade();
            o.setID_Materia(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Materia")));
            o.setMateria(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Descricao")));
            o.setPeriodo(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Periodo")));
            o.setDiaSemana(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Dia_Semana")));

            list.add(o);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have multiple databases then you would have to attach on to the other to use a join (or create temporary tables ). **i.e. your issues is that Materias table is in another unattached database, so the GradeDao does not know about the Materias table in the Materias Database which is connected via the MateriaDao.** You probably do not need multiple databases (a database can have multiple tables) and therefore multiple subclasses of SQLiteOpenHelper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that have seperate/distinct connections/databases. That is **GradeDao** is one connection/database and **MateriaDao** is another. **They are independent of each other and know nothing about each other.**

As such **GradeDao** does not know that there is a table called **Materias** in  **MateriaDao**.

You could attach the **Materias** database to the **GradeDao** database [SQL As Understood By SQLite - ATTACH DATABASE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html)

However, I would suggest that in all likiehood a single database with multiple tables would be simpler to work with (one of the things about a Relational Database Management System is that realtionships (tables that relate to each other) has relational in the name).